Now that the best AI system is equivalent to ranked #175 best human competitive coder on the planet (Codeforces), can we allow its use for code gen?
AI systems are not allowed on SO for code generation (and more generally, to write answers). The decision was made 2 years ban, i.e. 2 centuries ago in genAI years. Now, the best AI system is ranked #175 best human competitive coder on Codeforces (OpenAI official source; mirror of the Codeforces rating page on 2024-12-20), i.e. smokes almost all of us for code generation. Therefore, isn't it about time that we start allowing the use of such systems or superior ones on SO for code generation?

Comments have been moved to chat.

Considering the amount of respect competitive coding gets around here the opinion needle is hardly going to move.
